# Subclassing a subclass of NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, inheritance, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have an `NSManagedObject` subclass directly generated from my Core Data model, and I receive the objects of such class' data from a web service in JSON format. So I need to extend the subclass with some parsing methods. Moreoverbut, I need to extend the objects by providing some attributes that I'm not interested in store into de database.

This is currently my code:

```
@interface Customer : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * firstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * familyName;
@end

@interface ExtCustomer : Customer
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *modificationDate;
+ (ExtCustomer *)parseJsonData:(NSData *)jsonData;
@end
```

I don't find examples of managing objects that inherit from an `NSManagedObject` subclass. I'm doing this way because I prefer to keep my custom logic and the attributes I don't want to persist apart from the class generated from the data model, in case I have to re-generate the data model. In addition, the class I want to use throughout the app is the child one, `ExtCustomer`. What is the correct or best way to manage the initialization of this subclass' objects? And how should I save them by means of Core Data? Simply saving them as `Customer` objects?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use mogenerator. It will generate two classes: _Entity and Entity. So you can write your custom variables and methods in Entity class that inherit from _Entity. In addition, you can set Run Script in Build Phases to execute automatically mogenerator command. For more details visit https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator.

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to avoid using third-parties to solve this if I can, but I've been looking at that and I'll use it if I don`t find another way